# Simple XML text parsing

Tags: xml, awk, sed, grep

Can someone please advise me what is the best way to get the mentioned output? I tried to use awk & print but don't know how to make the syntax correctly.

Input:

```
<client model="c" name="adam" desc="desc1" prot="prot1" proe="proe1" au="0" thid="id_0x7f24b00ff1f0">
<request_ccd="0100" serv="123" emt="48" emtha="48" answ="0100"></request>
<times login="2014-07-06T14:25:23+0200" uptime="18285" idle="6"></times>
<connection_ip1="1.1.1.1" port="33612">OK</connection>
</client>
<client model="c" name="john" desc="desc2" prot="prot2" proe="proe2" au="0" thid="id_0x7f24b0038950">
<request_ccd="0200" serv="234" emt="237" emtha="13" answ="0200"></request>
<times login="2014-07-06T14:41:00+0200" uptime="17348" idle="4"></times>
<connection_ip2="2.2.2.2" port="37468">OK</connection>
</client>
<client model="c" name="james" desc="desc3" prot="prot3" proe="proe3" au="0" thid="id_0x7f24b0030b10">
<request_ccd="0300" serv="345" emt="299" emtha="22" answ="0300cyfr"></request>
<times login="2014-07-06T14:45:01+0200" uptime="17107" idle="6"></times>
<connection_ip3="3.3.3.3" port="46948">OK</connection>
</client>
```

Expected output:

```
adam    prot1   1.1.1.1 0100 123
john    prot2   2.2.2.2 0200 234
james   prot3   3.3.3.3 0300 345
```

Comment: What fields of the input is that output populated from? `name`, `prot`, `request_ccd`, and `serv`?

Comment: Also this sort of thing would almost certainly be better done with something like xslt than with something like awk/sed/grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `FS` and `RS` carefully shows the power of `GNU awk` off nicely for this kind of problem:

```
$ awk '{print $4,$8,$32,$16,$18}' FS='"' RS='</client>' file
adam prot1 1.1.1.1 0100 123
john prot2 2.2.2.2 0200 234
james prot3 3.3.3.3 0300 345
```

If your actual XML is different from your example then the following script will help to get the field numbers that you want:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print i,$i}' FS='"' RS='</client>' file
```

This will enumerate the fields in your first record allowing you to selected the ones you want.

Comment: thats exactly what i needed, thank you all guys for your good work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility. It's not very robust, though.

```
awk '
  $3 ~ /name=/                { split($3, a, "\""); name = a[2] }
  $5 ~ /prot=/                { split($5, a, "\""); prot = a[2] }
  $1 ~ /request_ccd=/         { split($1, a, "\""); ccd  = a[2] }
  $2 ~ /serv=/                { split($2, a, "\""); serv = a[2] }
  $1 ~ /connection_ip[0-9]+=/ { split($1, a, "\""); ip   = a[2] }
  /<\/client>/ {printf("%-8s %-7s %s %s %s\n", name, prot, ip, ccd, serv)}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `gnu awk`

```
awk -v RS="<client" 'NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,"=*\"");arr[a[1]]=a[2]}print arr["name"], arr["prot"], arr["<connection_ip1"], arr["<request_ccd"], arr["serv"]}'
adam prot1 1.1.1.1 0100 123
john prot2 1.1.1.1 0200 234
james prot3 1.1.1.1 0300 345
```

You just write what field you like.  Even if fields are missing or in other order, this will work.
But not if there are space in the fields.

Comment: @iiSeymour Fixed my code.  Its no problem comments other persons code. We all learn from it.  I did a typo, and did write what is the pitfall of my code (space in fields)

Comment: You're right but it goes both ways. You've answer over 1000 question an haven't earned the sportsmanship badge and have a low number of votes in general.

Comment: @iiSeymour I am here to learn and help, not to earn points. I think its important to mention when some one use a solution that is not 100% portable (like gnu awk).  Its more important that the user learns from this compare to click +1 on my comments.